# What is the "best" filesystem for Timemachine (Samba fruit) on a Linux host (Debian)

Tags: filesystems, samba

### Question

Looking for a canonical, fact-based answer to the question what filesystem is the "best" (if any) in terms of operational performance to serve an OSX Timemachine service from Samba using Fruit on a Linux host.

### Context

I'm running Debian Bullseye (11.6) Linux on a modest home server. My laptop is an Apple (M1 Pro) laptop. Network is 1Gbps. On my server, I run a Timemachine service using [Samba Fruit](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configure_Samba_to_Work_Better_with_Mac_OS_X). My question is if the underlying filesystem where the timemachine data is stored has a *measurable and significant* effect on the performance of the Timemachine service.

My server used to run madam RAID10 with ext4 and recently I migrated to Btrfs (also RAID10,managed by Btrfs). Since Btrfs is a COW filesystem, and Timemachine works by writing its own sparse files, which feels like duplicating some of the COW functionality. I didn't do any measurements (madam + ext4 vs Btrfs), but I don't experience a significant performance increase or decrease. You can find many opinions about this for example on Reddit (such as [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/ihzh5l/macos_backup_time_machine_or_clone_to_btrfs_with/), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/synology/comments/680re7/does_btrfs_provide_significant_benefit_over_ext4/), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/83vkaz/howto_make_time_machine_backups_on_a_samba/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/btrfs/comments/guezmm/btrfs_as_time_machine_target/)), but I find it hard to find fact based (non-opinionated) answer. I would like to know if the underlying filesystem has a (significant) effect on the timemachine (Samba Fruit) performance.

Since this is a common use-case (running Timemachine on Linux), I think a fact-based, canonical answer to this question is fitting on this site. Also: since this is about a Linux service, I think this question actually belongs here and not on AskDifferent).

Comment: By "performance", do you mean data throughput in reading/writing a large file or response time when listing a folder with many small files? Maybe time to update a large file in-place when data in the middle of the file is altered? Do you have hardware raid on the server? If not, are you using md devices, file system raid through zfs, or maybe lvm raid volumes?

Answer (score -1):

I personally ran a few tests using different underlying filesystems and found absolutely no performance difference - all of my backups were network constrained.

I do now wonder, however, if netatalk will provide a performance increase over Samba.

Stay tuned when I have more spare time...

Comment: This sounds like a progress report on an ongoing troubleshooting/problem investigation. As such, it should not be posted as an answer - the answer section is reserved for definitive solutions to the original problem.